# How to use UISwipeGestureRecognizer in Xamarin?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

How do I use UISwipeGestureRecognizer in Xamarin? This is the code I have so far and it not working, when I swipe nothing happens.

```
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        ImageView.Image = new UIImage((string)ListOfImages[0]);

        var swipeRight = new UISwipeGestureRecognizer(this, new ObjCRuntime.Selector("swiped:"));
        swipeRight.Direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right;
        ImageView.AddGestureRecognizer(swipeRight);
    }
    public void swiped(UIGestureRecognizer gesture)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("User swiped right");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to export the method using the same name as the selector that you used:

```
[Export("swiped:")]
public void swiped(UIGestureRecognizer gesture)
{
    Console.WriteLine("User swiped right");
}
```

Or use the overload that accepts a C# `Action`:

```
var swipeRight = new UISwipeGestureRecognizer(swiped);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var swipeRight = new UISwipeGestureRecognizer((s) => { swiped(s); });

private void swiped(UISwipeGestureRecognizer s) {
     Console.WriteLine("User swiped right");  
}
```

Comment: Please provide additional context to the code, as it might not be as helpful as it could be.